# Regex Remove From x To y

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to regex, I know the basics but only the basics. I need to parse a string to remove all occurances of one string to another. For example,

```
Here is some random text
This wants to stay
foo
This wants to be removed 
bar
And this wants to stay
```

So the desired output would be

```
Here is some random text
This wants to stay
And this wants to stay
```

And removed would be

```
foo
This wants to be removed
bar
```

It will always follow the pattern of match 'this string' to 'that string' and remove everything in between, including 'this string' and 'that string'.

The file is a text file, for the sake of this question, the pattern will always start with foo and end with bar, removing foo, bar and everything in between.

Foo and Bar ARE part of the file and need removing.

Comment: Which lang you're running? Any attempts?

Comment: No attempts - planning stage at the moment but i'm writing it in Perl, I planned on using RegEx to detect the pattern which I could then cut out using Perl. My Perl knowledge is also limited however, this is more of a learning experience for me.

Comment: @ndn I dont think the `##start##` is a part of the file, but rather a comment he left to show where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$start = "foo";
$end = "bar";
while (<STDIN>) {
$str = $str . $_;
}
$str =~ s/(.*)$start\n.*$end\n(.*)/\1\2/s;
print $str;
```

The only part of real importance to you is the regex I suppose, but I declare the start and end, then read from standard input and tack each concurrent line onto $str.  Then I take str and say "whatever is the first thing within perenthesis before foo put first, whatever is in the second after bar parenthesis put last" (with the backslash \1 and \2)

My output from a file containing your lines is:

```
marshall@marshall-desktop:~$ cat blah | ./haha 
Here is some random text
This wants to stay
And this wants to stay
```

Comment: That works mostly like how I want, the way it's called is a bit different to how I wanted but I can fiddle with that, the main thing I needed was the RegEx pattern - thanks!

Comment: If there are multiple occurrences of the deletion markers, then you'll want to change that middle `.*` to `.*?`. Also, you can simplify the substitution to `$str =~ s/$start\n.*$end\n//s;`

Comment: A nicer way to read a whole file is `my $str = do { local $/; <STDIN> };`. But I'd always prefer something that works line by line rather than slurping in the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

Regexes are probably the wrong tool here. I'd probably use string equality along with the flip-flop operator.

```
while (<$input_fh>) {
  print $output_fh unless ($_ eq "foo\n" .. $_ eq "bar\n");
}
```

You could do it with a regex and a match operator.

```
while (<$input_fh>) {
  print $output_fh unless /foo/ .. /bar/;
}
```

That looks neater, but the regexes will match if the strings appear anywhere on an input line.

**Update:** Inverted the logic on the tests - so it's now correct.

Comment: Neat way to put my words into practice. Completely forgot about flip flops. +1.

Comment: The text I need to find will never appear on the input line. I plan on calling the perl script on the text file, which then edits the text file and outputs a modified version, e.g, ./script this_file.txt the text file is then modified, one of the modifications would be cutting out any text between and including two hard coded strings, these strings will never change and always need removing fully regardless of what is between the two strings, no exceptions. Another modification it would be doing is from a certain pattern to the top of the file, but I already have that sorted out.

Comment: If you're sure that the start and end markers won't appear anywhere else in the file, then the regex version will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what RegEx is there for. RegEx is there to detect pattern - if you want simple string slice, you should simply iterate over the big string with a simple comparison (or, with other languages which include string operations, `indexOf("your string here");` etc. )

However, simple typing of the string would find you the matches:
`This wants to be removed` will return all occurances of that specific string, and thus it is fit for you.

Comment: The text inside the two areas will change and I have no idea what it could be in any circumstance. The starting text and ending text will always be the same, which is why I planned on using RegEx to find the starting pattern and ending pattern, then pass all of that to Perl to cut it out.

Comment: @NathanAudsley How do you know what is the text between the two areas? What do you know about the structure of the files? Add that to your question, it's relevant.

Comment: I do not know what the text is. I know it will always follow the pattern 

    Blah
    Blah
    foo
    random text
    could be anything
    bar
    more text to keep